# Update a MS Access table using a formula stored in another table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have one table called PayerFormulas that includes a different formula for each payer. Another table is PayerData that has the payer and the data we receive. I want to populate PayerData.CheckNum using the appropriate formula stored in PayerFormulas. The CheckNum data in the table below is what I would like the result to be.

In pseudocode it feels like this is what I'm looking for.

```
Update PayerData PD
inner join PayerFormulas PF on PD.Payer = PF.Payer
set PD.Check = PF.Formula
```

I've tried the above in a regular Access query and it doesn't work. Trying the following code only puts the formula text in the table, not the result. I've looked at using Eval() in some way, but since my result will often include text, it doesn't look like the route to go down..

```
Sub testFormula()

Dim SQLString As String
Dim ActiveQuery As QueryDef

SQLString = "Update PayerData PD inner join PayerFormulas PF on PD.Payer = PF.Payer set PD.CheckNum = PF.Formula"

Set ActiveQuery = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", SQLString)
ActiveQuery.Execute dbFailOnError

End Sub
```

PayerFormulas table

```
Payer      | Formula
-----------|--------
Visa       | mid([PayerData].[Data],3,2)
Mastercard | left([PayerData].[Data],2)
Amex       | right([PayerData].[Data],2)
```

PayerData table

```
Payer      |  Data  | CheckNum
-----------|--------|---------
Visa       | 123456 | 34
Visa       | ABCDEF | CD
Visa       | qwerty | er
Mastercard | 123456 | 12
Mastercard | ABCDEF | AB
Mastercard | qwerty | qw
Amex       | 123456 | 56
Amex       | ABCDEF | EF
Amex       | qwerty | ty
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, to continue with the original example of 3 formulas. Your idea to use Eval() is valid but have to concatenate the variable provided by [Data] field. Modify the formulas table to break up the function parts into separate fields.

```
Payer      | Func   | Arg1 | Arg2
-----------|---------------------
Visa       | mid    |  3   | 2
Mastercard | left   |  2   |
Amex       | right  |  2   |
```

Then in the query that joins tables:

`CheckNum: Eval([Func] & "('" & [Data] & "', " & [Arg1] & ", " & [Arg2] & ")")`

Note the apostrophe delimiters around [Data].

Or the args can be in one field and entered as comma separated value: 3, 2. Then:

`CheckNum: Eval([Func] & "('" & [Data] & "', " & [Args] & ")")`

Or, if you really want the formula in one field, enter it as: `Mid(PayData,3,2)`, `Left(PayData,2)`, `Right(PayData,2)`. Then in query calculation, Replace PayData with value of Data field:

`CheckNum: Eval(Replace([Formula], "PayData", "'" & [Data] & "'"))`

BTW, don't really need to save the result to table, calculate when needed.

Comment: The eval function works great! Thank you! If I were to take this a step further, is there a way to make a priority order with this as well? For instance, if I also had data where Payer may be Amjet, Amway, etc and I  wanted to set a PayerFormula rule for Am*. Such that when Data.Payer = Amex to hit on that specific formula, but the other 'Am's to hit on Am*.

Comment: Requires complicated IIf() expression or custom VBA function. Kinda defeats purpose of table. Just how many formula variations are there?

Answer (score 1):

Only 3 formulas? Use conditional code in the VBA. Send a card identifier to the procedure as an argument:

```
Sub testFormulat(strC As String)
Dim result As String

Select Case strC
    Case "Visa"
        result = Mid(Me.Data, 3, 2)
    Case "Mastercard"
        result = Left(Me.Data, 2)
    Case "AMEX"
        result = Right(Me.Data, 2)
End Select

CurrentDb.Execute "Update PayerData set CheckNum = '" & result & "' WHERE ID = " & Me.ID

End Sub
```

Where will the Data value come from? Is code behind a form? Is form bound to the table result needs to be saved in? If so, the SQL is not needed, simply:
Me!PayerData = result

Comment: This was a simplified version of my final table. There will be 30+ formulas. Which I could still make as a case statement but putting into a table feels a lot cleaner and easier to maintain. There is no form. It's all tables, queries, VBA. The data is getting imported via an import macro and will have 100s of rows a day. I used this smaller version to cover the code I was stumped on, thinking I can take the rest from here. At this time, we have 30 different queries, then a macro that calls one after the other. Which works, but again, feels dirty.